# How can I disable the studentd process?

Tags: macos, mdm

When I see a `studentd` process in Activity Monitor or a `studentd` directory in `~/Library` I wonder [what is `studentd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/357284/435523)?

2019 Macbook Air running Catalina (10.15.7)

In the linked answer I learned that it is for studends and teachers that use Apple Classroom, however I do not and will probably never use Apple Classroom, so as far as I am concerned `studentd` is bloatware

Even if there are side effects or stability issues, I would like to experiment and use `launchctl disable` to disable this processs. Specifically, I researched and think perhaps deleting `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.macos.studentd.plist` s might work. Or could `/usr/libexec/studentd` and all other related files be deleted too?

I’d like guidance on altering permissions on my system to perform this surgery. Can you point me to some steps for this?

Comment: I also noticed that `/usr/libexec/studentd` was created almost one year after I got and started using this computer, so what also update would have caused this to be added?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running and on what _model_ of **Mac**?

Comment: Looking on a system running **macOS Catalina**, `studentd` is loaded by a _launch agent_, `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.macos.studentd.plist`. -- `launchctl` needs to be used to deal with it. In **Terminal** use: `man launchctl`

Comment: On my computer is uses 12 MB of memory (versus 310 MB for this webpage alone) and 0.0% CPU. Any tweaks to disable this would likely impose a bigger liability than is worth it for 12 MB of RAM being recovered..

Comment: @Ezekiel See comments on [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/357285/435523)

Comment: This is an excellent question. I’ve made some edits so that it’s not a sequence of new questions but the core remains. We don’t have to agree with any reasons _why_ someone would want to customize their OS. I think we should band together to explain how to do it and maybe report risks / breakage.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the edit and I agree

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to remove all the files etc, too. But I can't find a comprehensive trustworthy source for doing that. So for now, I disabled using launchctl:

```
sudo launchctl disable system/studentd
```

And I haven't noticed any side-effects.

As an precaution, I removed the default 'allow' access to the login certificate for studentd in KeyChain Access

How: find the login cert in the Keychain app (Name begins with 'member: ', expand the item to reveal the private cert and double click. Remove studentd from the 'Always allow..' list.

Be sure to select 'Confirm before allowing access'

Comment: `sudo launchctl disable system/studentd` did not seem to stop studentd from appearing in Activity Monitor

Comment: The disable command disables the auto launch config. Try either kill  -9 <pid> or reboot